# Implementation of Rabin-Karp string matching (Rolling hash)

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, hash, string-matching

I am trying to implement [Rabin-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) string matching algorithm to find String `needle` in String `haystack` (Return index of String `haystack` where a match for String `needle` was found). I am getting error in trying to find needle `c` in haystack `abc`.

Here is how my output looks after running my code for finding `c` in `abc`:

> hayHash: 0 and needleHash: 2 at i: 0 remove: a and add: b and new hash
> is before checking for negatives: 1
>
> hayHash: 1 and needleHash: 2 at i: 1 remove: b and add: c and new hash
> is before checking for negatives: -50
>
> hayHash: 51 and needleHash: 2

I can't figure why the last hash recount calculates to `-50` and not `2` for `hayHash`. Here both `hayHash` and `needleHash` should be a calculated hash consisting of only char `'c'`, and should be the same value for both. But my code is recalculating `hayHash` to `51` (`-50` before cancelling negative value) instead of `2`.

Any suggestions on what might be wrong in my code?

Here is my code:

```
private fun find(haystack: String, needle: String): Int {
    if(needle.length > haystack.length) return -1

    val q = 101
    val d = 256
    var needleHash = 0
    var hayHash = 0
    var hash = 1

    for (i in 0..needle.length)
        hash = (hash * d) % q

    for(i in 0..needle.lastIndex) {
        needleHash = (d * needleHash + (needle[i] - 'a')) % q
        hayHash = (d * hayHash + (haystack[i] - 'a')) % q
    }

    for(i in 0..(haystack.length - needle.length)) {
        println("hayHash: $hayHash and needleHash: $needleHash")
        if(hayHash == needleHash) {
            for(j in 0..needle.lastIndex) {
                if(haystack[i + j] != needle[j])
                    break
                if(j == needle.lastIndex)
                    return i
            }
        }
        if(i == haystack.length - needle.length)
            break
        print("at i: $i remove: ${haystack[i]} and add: ${haystack[i + needle.length]}")   
        hayHash = (d * (hayHash - (haystack[i]  - 'a') * hash) + (haystack[i + needle.length]  - 'a')) % q
        println(" and new hash is before checking for negatives: $hayHash")
        if(hayHash < 0)
            hayHash += q
    }

    return -1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One part is pre-computing the wrong power of *d*.
The other is multiplying not only the character leaving the window with this power, but the difference from the current *hayHash*.
Try `hayHash = (d * hayHash - ((haystack[i]  - 'a') * hash) + (haystack[i + needle.length] - 'a')) % q`

Answer (score 2):

`for (i in 0..needle.length)` while initializing `hash` is an off-by-one error. You want `for(i in 0..needle.lastIndex)`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. You are correct about that. I changed that but the outcome is still wrong (albeit a bit different hash calculated now). Running the same code for same test case where haystack = "abc" and needle = "c" the last hash calculation gives me a hayHash of 69 after cancelling out the negative value of -32. Got any ideas?